# redirect based on referrer URL (not working for query string)

Tags: php, nginx

We have redirected `www.old-domain.com` to `www.new-domain.com` as we are not using old site any more.
So, `www.old-domain.com/whatever` redirects to `www.new-domain.com/whatever`. But this causes 404 errors as we don't have those pages.
So I tried to redirect everything from old-domain to the homepage of new-domain as:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'old-domain.com') !== false) {
    @header("Location: http://new-domain.com/");
    exit;
}
```

This works fine but not with query string in the url.
For example: `www.old-domain/whatever/?utm=123` redirects to the `www.new-domain.com/?utm=123`
Note the query string is preserved in new url which I don't want.

Note that I even used meta tag & Javascript based redirection but case is still the same.

Anyway to fix the error? Really appreciate your inputs. (we are using nginx server)

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your nginx configuration file.

```
server {
  server_name .old-domain.com;
  rewrite ^ http://new-domain.com/ permanent;
}
```

Comment: I want everything redirected to the base url. For example: old-domain/whatever/?utm=1&xyz=2 -> new-domain.com

Comment: @MagePsycho so you want the URI in the redirect as well? See my updated question.

Comment: I want everthing from old-domain redirected to the base url of new domain i.e. new-domain.com (without any path, query string etc.)

Comment: The `rewrite` rule can be replaced with the equivalent but shorter `return 301 http://new-domain.com/;`. (Thanks, double_p.)

Answer (score 1):

It is much better to no to involve PHP for this job. This is suited more for .htaccess.

Place this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://new-domain.com/? [L,R=301]
```

Trailing `?` will strip off existing query string.

Comment: We are using nginx server and that doesn't use .htaccess for server config.

Comment: I'm sure nginx has similar directive for rewriting